# double quoted private key stored in jenkins secret text not masking the output

Tags: docker, jenkins

I have stored secret text in jenkins credentials with two format

**secret text without quotes throwing error**  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabcdefxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyy=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n

**secret text with quotes no error but key not masking**   "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nabcdefxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyy=\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n"

```
pipeline {
agent any

environment {
client_id="12345"
client_email=test123@test.com
project_key=credentials('patapps')
}

stages {
stage ('build'){
  steps {
    sh "docker build -t apps:latest"
    }   
    }
}
stage ('docker run'){
  steps {
    sh "docker run --network host --name automation -e CLIENT_ID=${env.client_id} -e CLIENT_EMAIL=${env.client_email} -e PROJECT_KEY=${env.project_key} -t apps:latest"
    }   
    }
}
}
}
```

when we execute above code I am getting an error like

*+ docker run --network host --name automation -e 'CLIENT_ID=12345' -e 'CLIENT_EMAIL=test123@test.com' -e 'PRIVATE_KEY=-----BEGIN' PRIVATE 'KEY-----
nabcdefxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxyyyyyyyyyyyy=n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----n
docker: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase.
See 'docker run --help'*

**Same project key when I try to store in double quotes inside jenkins credentials code is working fine without any error but the issue is project key not getting masked since the value in double quotes its printing value in the Jenkins console**

How can I mask those project key by storing keys as secret text with double quotes in jenkins credentials ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jenkins `sh` command runs a shell to interpret the string it's given.  This means that you should use a single-quoted Groovy string (so that Groovy doesn't try to expand `$variable` references) and you should use Bourne shell syntax inside the string (`$variable`, not `${env.variable}`).

```groovy
sh 'docker run ... -e "CLIENT_ID=$client_id" ... apps:latest'
#                                ^^^^^^^^^^ shell variable expansion
#                     ^....................^ double-quoted shell word
#  ^... single-quoted Groovy string ........................^
```

If you do it this way then the text `CLIENT_ID=$client_id` will be logged, but not the actual value of the variable; that will be expanded by the shell that `sh` launches.

Another thing you can do to simplify things is to take advantage of `docker run -e NAME` with no value passes through that variable from the host environment into the container.  This means you need to make your Jenkins environment-variable names match what the container expects.

```groovy
environment {
  CLIENT_ID="12345"
}
stages {
  stage ('docker run'){
    steps {
      sh 'docker run ... -e CLIENT_ID ... apps:latest'
      #                     ^^^^^^^^^ name, but no value
    }
  }
}
```